# Avoid spurious warnings in a parasitic class with key-value options (LaTeX3 \DeclareKeys)

Tags: latex3, warnings, documentclass-writing, key-value, class-options

This is a modified version of ["Unused global options(s)" when using arguments in options of class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/682439/). The question is how to create a parasitic class (i.e. one which loads another) which accepts key-value options specific to that class, but does not generate warnings about unknown options.

Consider,

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{\jobname}
\DeclareOption{bertha}{}
\DeclareKeys[testwork]{%
  test .code ={\newcommand{\foo}{#1}},
  test .usage = load,
}
\ProcessKeyOptions[testwork]
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}

\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{article}

\endinput
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[test=wtf,bertha]{\jobname}

\begin{document}
test \foo
  
\end{document}
```

Compiling this example produces the typeset result expected, but the messages printed to the terminal and recorded in the log are not quite as expected.

```
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [test].
```

In the original question, the key-value option is created using `xkeyval`. I could not figure out how to avoid the warning in that case, but I hoped that using the built-in framework for declaring key-value options would be handled better.

According to `clsguide.pdf` only options not declared by the parasitic class should be passed to `article`. This is true, for example, of `bertha`. But it is not, apparently, true of `test`. Moreover, if `test=wtf` was passed to `article`, I'd expect it to be passed together with its value i.e. I'd expect a warning about `test=wtf` as opposed to `test`.

Obviously, I'm not setting this up correctly, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. How is this supposed to be done exactly?

Comment: Thats indeed a very interesting question. The warning is not a big thing if you're the only one who uses the class. But if you're writing a `.cls` file which might be used in your company, is distributed via GitHub/Lab etc. or will be submitted to CTAN, those warnings could confuse other users.

Comment: You should use a more reliable package that actually documents that you can use `\CurrentOption` like `expkv-opt` :P

Comment: @Skillmon Or I should use a more reliable source of information, but those comments have been disappeared ;).

Comment: @cfr btw. `expkv` separates between keys taking a value and keys not taking a value, so `bertha` could be an option that really doesn't want a value (and would throw an error accordingly if given one -- you could use the `.value_forbidden:n` property to get the same behaviour in `l3keys`).

Comment: */commercial ends*

Comment: @Skillmon The thing is, I really like the key-value handling in `expl3`'s programming layer. I used `\DeclareKeys` for the example, but I've never actually used it. I just use `\keys_define:nn` etc.

Comment: @cfr which is fine by me (and I like it as well -- and if you use it you're still using code by me, though most of it was done by Joseph :P).

Comment: @Skillmon I know you're part of the team ;). I trust your code. I'm just trying to avoid tangling with yet another key-value framework. I've already got `xkeyval`, `pgfkeys`, the l3 stuff and maybe some older interfaces, while packages I use load `kvoptions` etc., too. I can't avoid multiple methods entirely, but I'd like to keep the setup as simple as practicable. (And I'm sure if I tried your package, I'd want to use it, so I'd best not ;).)

Comment: Oh, I'm not part of the team. I'm just a loosely attached collaborator sometimes doing reviews or making code suggestions. And nothing is wrong with using `l3keys`. In fact, nowadays I'd only suggest using three packages for key=value stuff (one of which I'm fairly biased with :) and one of which I'd only use if the underlying code is using `pgf` or Ti*k*Z anyway; the third you might be able to guess from the previous sentence).

Comment: @Skillmon Indeed, though I already knew. The only reason I mentioned `xkeyval` is because I've got custom classes/packages which I've not rewritten and still use it. Like you, I really use `pgfkeys` only when I'm dealing with `pgf/tikz` anyway. (`prooftrees`, `forest`, `chronos` ...). And half the time I'm passing stuff from `pgfkeys` to `expl3` stuff anyway. (In fact, I even use l3keys for the colour scheme interface for `chronos` because it's so much easier - for me - to process the keys selectively.)

Comment: BTW: you might consider not only forwarding unknown options, but turning around things. First doing a `\LoadClassWithOptions{article}`, and afterwards running `\ProcessKeyOptions` -- and dropping the unknown option handling altogether. Behaviour would be different if your class happens to define a key that is already a known option to `article` (with your approach `article` wouldn't see its option, implementing means to filter out options for `article`, if that's never the case then it's really not worth the hassle)

Answer (score 10):

You are mixing two option systems and that confuses the setting of the unused lists handling as for every system a different option is "unknown" and so unused.

Stick to one system (that one can use `\CurrentOption` in `\DeclareUnknownKeyHandler` is not documentated, we should change that ;-)).

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{testoption.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{testoption}
\DeclareKeys[testwork]{%
  bertha .code={},
  test .code ={\newcommand{\foo}{#1}},
  test .usage = load  
}
\DeclareUnknownKeyHandler [testwork]
 {\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}

\ProcessKeyOptions[testwork]
\LoadClass{article}
\endinput
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[test=wtf,bertha,12pt]{testoption}

\begin{document}
test \foo
  
\end{document}
```

Comment: @cabohah probably. large sets of generic keyval options in class options are imho problematic anyway.  I would avoid to stress the system here too much.

Comment: @cabohah But wouldn't you want it to result in errors in that case?

Comment: Or is the problem that `=` gets added? In my initial example, I didn't actually have `bertha`, but only `test=wtf` (following the linked question). So does any use of the key-value interface here require treating all options as key-value to avoid warnings? I.e. even if the base class doesn't itself use key-value syntax?

Answer (score 6):

The problem seems to be using `\ProcessKeyOptions` and `\ProcessOptions`. Instead, I would use:

```latex
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{\jobname}
\DeclareKeys[testwork]{%
  test .code ={\newcommand{\foo}{#1}},
  test .usage = load,
  bertha .code = {},
  bertha .value_forbidden:n = true,
}
\DeclareUnknownKeyHandler[testwork]{%
  \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}%
}
\ProcessKeyOptions[testwork]\relax

\LoadClass{article}

\endinput
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[test=wtf,bertha,alpha,gamma=true,12pt]{\jobname}

\begin{document}
test \foo
  
\end{document}
```

The

> `(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo)`

in the `log`-file shows, that option `12pt` is correctly passed to and recognized by `article.cls`.

The message:

> ```
>  LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
>      [alpha,gamma].
> ```

shows, that the two unknown options are correctly result in warning messages.

Note: For key-value options, LaTeX always reports only the key as unknown. This is a feature.

---

**Addendum:** Using this suggestion does also work, if the loaded class itself processes key-value options:

```latex
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{test.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{\jobname}
\DeclareKeys[testwork]{%
  test .code ={\newcommand{\foo}{#1}},
  test .usage = load,
  bertha .code = {},
  bertha .value_forbidden:n = true,
}
\DeclareUnknownKeyHandler[testwork]{%
  \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{test-base}%
}
\ProcessKeyOptions[testwork]\relax

\LoadClass{\jobname-base}

\endinput
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{test-base.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{\jobname-base}
\DeclareKeys{%
  gamma .code= \typeout{Gamma=`#1'},
  gamma .value_required:n =true
}
\DeclareUnknownKeyHandler{%
  \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}
}
\ProcessKeyOptions
\LoadClass{article}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[test=wtf,bertha,alpha,gamma=test,gamma=,12pt]{test}

\begin{document}
test
  
\end{document}
```

Here you can also see, that `gamma=` is passed as `gamma=` from `test` to `test-base`. (If is would be passed as `gamma`, an error would be reported, because `gamma` requires a value.)

Comment: ah, right one could use \CurrentOption for the whole option in the key handler too ;-)

Comment: So both key-value and non-key-value options would be passed to the base class in this case @UlrikeFischer ? Perhaps I didn't read the documentation carefully enough ....

Comment: @cfr The `\DeclareUnknownKeyHandler` does handle all unknown keys, because it does not know, whether an unknown option would be used as a key-value option without passing a value or as a non key-value option. I've shown this in my answer with options `alpha` and `12pt`. Both are passed to `article`. Maybe I should extend it by another option `gamma=true` and show the resulting log …

Comment: @cabohah I think it's fine. If this is the way to do it (or whatever the way to do it is), I think it should be in the documentation. Do you know where `\declarekeyoption` is documented? David mentions it in a comment above, but I can't find it. I don't think you should delete this answer ;).

Comment: @cfr no hit in my entire TeX Live 2023 installation for `\declarekeyoption` in any file of the types tex, sty, cls, or ltx.

Comment: @Skillmon David got it wrong, but Joseph (I guess) deleted the evidence ;).

Comment: @cfr it sounds similar to the macros of `kvoptions`, though they use CamelCase, and have no "keyoption" but things like "StringOption".

Comment: @Skillmon https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64573867#64573867.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:** The first code block using `\ProcessKeyOptions` doesn't really work, as `\ProcessKeyOptions` will add all the unknown options to it to the unused-globals list, so if you use an option known to `article` but not your class you'd get a false positive. This is not the case for the `expkv-opt` using code block below, `\ekvoProcessGlobalOptions` only ever removes, never adds to the list of unused global options.

**EDIT2:** If one uses an `unknown` handler with the first code, one should get the desired behaviour, but currently (2023-11-20) there is a bug in the option handling (reported [#1183](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/1183)), that'll be likely fixed at least by LaTeX 2024-06-01.

---

I'd suggest to invert the logic. Instead of first parsing your class's options and forwarding the unknown ones to `article`, you could as well load `article` with the entire list, and afterwards parse your options. As long as your class doesn't define options which are valid for `article` as well this would essentially have the same behaviour with less struggle for your code (see the documentation of `\LoadClassWithOptions` in `clsguide.pdf`). The unused options list would still be the same:

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{\jobname}
\LoadClassWithOptions{article}

\DeclareKeys[testwork]{%
  test .code  = \newcommand{\foo}{#1},
  test .usage = load,
  % the following three lines give an equivalent definition of your bertha
  % option as defined with `\DeclareOption{bertha}{}`
  bertha .code = {},
  bertha .value_forbidden:n = true,
  bertha .usage = load,
  # ignore unknown options to not add them to the unused options list
  unknown .code = {}
}
\ProcessKeyOptions[testwork]

\endinput
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[test=wtf,bertha]{\jobname}

\begin{document}
test \foo
\end{document}
```

---

And since I have to advertise, this is the equivalent code using `expkv`:

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{\jobname}
\LoadClassWithOptions{article}
\RequirePackage{expkv-opt,expkv-def}
\ekvdefinekeys{testwork}
  {%
    % `store` isn't really equivalent to your newcommand-using code, that
    % would've been:
    %   code test = \newcommand\foo{#1}
    % Instead `store` is equivalent to ltkeys' `.store` handler.
     store test    = \foo
    ,noval bertha  = {}
  }
% if a standard class was already loaded by \LoadClassWithOptions in a parasitic
% class the unused options list is already filled, we don't need to parse local
% options any more, and only having the package's default handling of global
% options is fine.
\ekvoProcessGlobalOptions{testwork}

\endinput
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[test=wtf,bertha]{\jobname}

\begin{document}
test \foo
  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Why doesn't this give a warning when `article` processes the options? Will the parasitic class still get options if `article` offers the same options?

Comment: @cfr both classes will completely digest all options given to your class. The standard class (`article`) will set the unused option list to contain all the options it doesn't know, and the option processing done by your class will remove the options it knows from the unused option list.

Comment: @cfr I just realised, there is an issue with my suggested approach if you're using `\ProcessKeyOptions`: your class will add the keys not known to it to the unused globals list (even if that list already has contents). The `expkv-opt` variant doesn't have that issue though, as you're using `\ekvoProcessGlobalOptions`.

Comment: It seems to me there isn't a great built-in solution here. All the answers feel like workarounds. Or not exactly workarounds, but there should be a standard, documented way of doing this which can be easily applied. The current dual-system setup in LaTeX seems non-optimal.

Comment: @cfr it is non-optimal, agreed, but it is optimal without breaking all the existing documents, classes and packages using the old system. It seems as in LaTeX2e's original design no one thought that one might want to use key=value options. Things might even be considered worse: With the raw option-list available, edge cases become actually harder to input, as your option has to survive an `\edef` without throwing errors, but is processed without an `\edef`-expansion applied. Something that `expkv-opt` doesn't do better -- I have no idea how that should be done better.

Comment: @Skillmon Indeed, the design of the original 2e code is really about supporting options as seen in 2.09, which are all simple strings

Comment: @cfr I'd say that the `\DeclareUnknownKeyHandler` setup as shown in the other answers is pretty much the direct equivalent of the old `\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}` approach. Though `\CurrentOption` should've been documented usable from the start.

Comment: @JosephWright If it isn't possible to avoid the two systems, could this at least be better documented? Maybe an example of how to do this correctly in `clsguide`? I don't think it can be such an unusual thing to want to do ....

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149131/discussion-on-answer-by-skillmon-avoid-spurious-warnings-in-a-parasitic-class-wi); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.